# 100 100 into 200

Tags: visual

[image: the numbers 100 and 100 hundred one over the other, and a line underneath both]

How do you make this into 200 only using 1 straight line?

Comment: Did you get this from somewhere? We require attribution for puzzles you didn't make yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately this is getting downvoted.  I think the reason is, you took a puzzle that is designed for oral delivery, and tried to convert it to text.  This approach usually works, but it doesn't in this particular case.   Keep contributing -  Don't let the downvotes discourage you.

Comment: This made sense to me. I thought it was a clever use of homophones.  Seems the main issue is whether it is original or improperly attributed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a little out-of-the-way here, and requires phonetical matching, but

> if you put a horizontal line on top of the first 1 to make it a T, you get "TOO 100", which could be read as "two hundred".

Comment: But the question asks for "...make this into 200... " and 200 is not the same as "T00 100"

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I agree that it is a weak puzzle/answer, but claiming that it's a problem because it's "not the same" kind of nullifies anything that's built on homophones or puns.